# for loop inside if condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

```
print "Select the action you want to perform(A or B)"
print "(A) uppper case"
print "(B) count number of lines"

option = raw_input("Enter your option(A or B):")

if option.upper() == "A":
    for line in x:
        line = line.upper()

    print line


elif option.upper() == "B":
    for line in x:
        line = line.upper()
        count = count + 1
    print "total lines:", count

else:
    print "incorrect option"
    exit()
```

When user enters **A** it prints only one line(last line) in upper case instead of 250 lines.

count works perfectly.

---

P.S. I have not submitted the first part of code which is for input of file name to be opened.

Comment: Put the print function inside the for loop so that it would print the current line on each iteration.

Comment: Oh okay thank you I was trying to do it from an hour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just indent your print statement as:

```
if option.upper() == "A":
    for line in x:
        line = line.upper()

        print line
```

In Python Indentation plays a very important role, by de indenting the print statement(as it was in the given code), the interpreter would consider it outside the `for` loop and it would be executed only once after the complete execution of `for` loop.

In order to execute the `print`statement at each iteration of the `for` loop you need to indent it inside the scope of for loop.

Comment: Oh okay thank you I was trying to do it from an hour.

Comment: Indentation sometimes freaks out beginners in Python. Don't worry. Keep practising

Answer (score 1):

the `print line` line should be indented to be inside the `for line in x` loop